# Adding items as range doesn't always trigger ItemsAdded for a ReactiveList

Tags: reactiveui

I have two `ReactiveList` called `ListA` and `ListB`. Any item added to `ListB` is also added to `ListA`:

```
this
    .WhenAnyValue(x => x.ListB)
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Subscribe(list =>
        {
            ListA.AddRange(list);
            list
                .ItemsAdded
                .Subscribe(item => ListA.Add(item), exceptionHandler)
                .DisposeWith(Disposables);
         })
    .DisposeWith(Disposables);
```

The issue is that when some UI action triggers `ListB.AddRange(items)`, `ListA` only gets properly updated when the number of `items` is small. When it's a few dozens, the `onNext` action of `ItemsAdded` is not called (and so is not `onError`) and I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReactiveList<T>` has been deprecated and we recommend the use of DynamicData https://github.com/rolandpheasant/DynamicData

The reason is due to a optimisation for UI where we will issue a reset instead when there is a large number of items.